# What's the point of questions with a bounty appearing in the low quality review queue?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, low-quality-posts, bounty

I received [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5300996) horrible question in the review queue.

Screenshot for posterity:

[image]

I was going to flag it as unclear, however I got the super-duper helpful message:

> This question has an open bounty and cannot be closed.

Since I cannot flag the question for closing, I skipped it. Why do these questions even show up in the queue?

---

I just ran into this again when trying to close [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5437607) as off-topic (more suitable for server fault).

Comment: You can use a custom flag in that case, a mod could refund the bounty and close the question (if they agree with you obviously).

Comment: @Mat That is not an option in the "Recommend Close" menu. But nice idea.

Comment: @SantaClaus: no, you need to visit the question via the link (in the sidebar under the question stats).

Comment: @Mat I thought bounties cannot be refund under any circumstances?

Comment: @MartijnPieters It makes no sense for the question to be in the low quality queue if it cannot be cleared through that queue.

Comment: @SantaClaus: This is an edge case, and I guess the issue has never come up before. It obviously *is* low quality.

Comment: @1337: mods can refund bounties, but AFAIK that only happens in cases like this (i.e. user shouldn't have been able to post the bounty in the first place since the question should have been closed). Don't even try to get a refund if you think it didn't generate enough attention/answers.

Comment: @Mat Haha no I won't, no worries.. :) But has this ever happened before (that a boundy actually got refund)?

Comment: @1337: yes. I've flagged for this once or twice already, and I'm pretty sure I'm not the only one. Probably find more info on this on MSE.

Comment: @Mat The problem with the custom flag is the current size of the mod queue, we've got 1.6k+ flags to review. By the time we get to a flag to refund a bounty, it's possible that there have been answers posted after the bounty that could win an auto award or the bounty has expired so there might not be anything for us to do.

Comment: @bluefeet: does that mean we should simply leave that sort of thing alone? (There's no other option for this, apart from commenting - and that's useless since even the OP can't do anything about it even if they were will to do anything.)

Comment: @Mat It's kind of a difficult situation due to the size of the mod work queue.  If you believe that this question needs to be closed before the bounty ends, then flag it for us to intervene.  Hopefully we will work through the flags fast enough to act.

Comment: @bluefeet Someone took care of the question however I still think something should be changed. Maybe add "Other (needs moderator attention)" should be added as a close reason in the LQ queue.

Comment: @SantaClaus Then that would be a `feature-request`

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121448/allow-users-to-vote-to-close-bountied-questions

Comment: Of course it kind of begs the question:  What use are bounties anyway?  I've never seen them actually accomplish anything.

Comment: @HotLicks Sounds like you need to post a question on MSE.

Comment: @SantaClaus - I'd sooner believe in Santa Claus than think that would do any good.

Comment: Here is another one: http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6194929

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yeah, there's not much point to this - we should be reserving such flags for moderators.

Answer (score -2):

They need to appear in the Low Quality queue in case they can be edited into shape.

Comment: Well... They can't.

Comment: @bjb568, no, many times they can be.

Comment: In any case, the 1% doesn't justify having items in the queue where the 50% (close) doesn't work.